# How to get object data into the jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm having a problem of not rendering the object data in the jsx. Here is the code.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { useEffect,useState } from 'react';



const Mapper=(props)=>{

    const currentCity=props.cities;
    console.log(currentCity);
    const mapped=currentCity.map(weatherDataMapper);
    const mappedObj=mapped[0];
    console.log(mappedObj);
    console.log(mappedObj.city);


    return (
        <ul>
            <li>yo wassup</li>
            {/* <li>{mappedObj.city}</li> */}
        </ul>
    );

}


export default Mapper;

function weatherDataMapper(data){

    const general={
      city:data.city.name,
      country:data.city.country,
      temperature:Math.round(data.list[0].main.temp),
      description:data.list[0].weather[0].description,
      humidity:data.list[0].main.humidity,
      icon:data.list[0].weather[0].icon,
      windSpeed:Math.round(data.list[0].wind.speed*3.6),
      feelsLike:Math.round(data.list[0].main.feels_like),
  
  
      
    }
  
  
    return general;
  }
```

i can get the mappedObj as a console output, but the 'mappedObj.city' couse an error "TypeError: can't access property "city", mappedObj is undefined". So how to solve this?? I'm a bit new to the react development btw.

Comment: Seems likely you are asynchronously fetch this data and on the initial component render it is undefined, i.e. `mapped[0]` is undefined. Try to include a more [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), your snippet appears neither complete nor repsoducible.

Comment: @DrewReese do you mean using useEffect??

Comment: Sure, maybe. The `useEffect` hook is commonly used to fetch/load data and set state.

Comment: @DrewReese i kind of realize that because when I add console.log into the code, page shows the object data(because of the live server). But when I only refresh the page it shows that error. So problem is that on the initial component render it is undefined. Any suggestions to fix it?

Comment: Use [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) to render alternative UI, or null, until the data is available to be rendered.

Comment: ok. I'll try that.